# Use Swift code in App made with Objective - C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am working on an application which is built in `objective C`.

I have to implement `UIActivityController` which is easy to implement using swift in any application but since I am not familiar with `Objective- C` even by a %, can I use `swift` code to implement the `UIActivityController` in a button?

If so, how?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can create `Swift` file, with your Swift implementation in the Objective-C project.

You just have to add

`#import "YourProjectName-Swift.h"`

into the objc file where you wanna call the swift code and execute it.

More info in article here for example https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/swift-and-objective-c-interoperability-2add8e6d6887